# python : Compute columns of data frames and add them to new columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to make a new column by calculating existing columns.
For example df

df
no    data1    data2
1      10        15
2      51        46
3      36        20
......

i want to make this

new_df
no    data1    data2    data1/-2    data1/2    data2/-2    data2/2
1      10       15         -5          5         -7.5        7.5
2      51       46        -25.5      25.5        -23         23
3      36       20         -18        18          -9         9

but i don't know how to make this as efficient as possible

Comment: Where do you want to make a new column? In a database?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new df column based on the calculations of two or more other columns, you would have to define a new column and set it equal to your equation. For example:

`df['new_col'] = df['col_1'] * df['col_2']`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? :

```
import pandas as pd

number = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(number)
df['Data 1/2'] = df[0] / df[1]
```

And the output :

```
    0   1   Data 1/2
0   1   2   0.500000
1   3   4   0.750000
2   5   6   0.833333
3   7   8   0.875000
4   9   10  0.900000
```